# Test for convergance the integral

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> 1. Test for convergance the integral $$ \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin4x \cos2x}{(x+1)^\frac{1}{3}} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

I'm confused with this integral because I can't find a comparison. $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ can't help us in solving this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Using the addition angle formula for the sine function, write $$\sin(4x)\cos(2x)=\frac12 \left(\sin(6x)+\sin(2x)\right)$$

Then, use the fact that  $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}\,dx$ converges for $0<a$ which is a consequence of [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals).

Comment: It won't help because $\frac{1}{(x+1)^{1/3}} > \frac1x$ for large $x$.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Really?  $x+1>x\implies \frac{1}{x+1}<\frac1x$.

Comment: I see you've edited the answer.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Yes, I took for granted familiarity with Dirichlet.

Comment: Still it's worth noting that comparison test won't be of use, as they require the absolute convergence of the integral you're comparing to. Your method can be used, but it requires shifting the variable, not comparison fo the integrals.

Answer (score 0):

This integral isn't absolutely convergent, that is $$ \int_1^\infty \left|\frac{\sin 4x\cos 2x}{(x+1)^{1/3}}\right|dx = \infty$$
which means that all comparison tests will be useless., as they can only be used to show absolute convergence. You'll need a completely different method.

Hint: define $$ a_n = (-1)^n\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\sin 4x\cos 2x}{(x+1)^{1/3}} dx$$
You have $$ \int_{\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin 4x\cos 2x}{(x+1)^{1/3}} dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$$
Try to show that $a_n > 0$ and $a_n \rightarrow 0$, and from the Leibniz critrion you'll get the convergence.

Comment: For Leibniz's test, $a_n\to 0$ is not sufficient.  If the terms decrease monotonically, then the conditions for Leibniz's test are satisfied.